# Why escape_javascript printed as text in coffeescript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, haml, kaminari

My goal is  to render a partial view after delete using Ajax to regenerate a table and its pagination. But when I try to do this in my `schedules.js.coffee`:

```
$(".delete_schedule").bind "ajax:success", ->
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut "slow", ->
  $("table tr.numbered_row:visible").each (i) -> 
    $(this).children(".seq").text i + 1
  $("#schedules").html('#{ escape_javascript render("schedules")}')
  $("#paginator").html('#{ escape_javascript(paginate(@schedules, :remote => true).to_s)}')
```

the page source of the output is like:

```
<tbody id="schedules">#{ escape_javascript render(:partial =&gt; "schedules")}</tbody>
<div id="paginator">#{ escape_javascript(paginate(@schedules, :remote =&gt; true).to_s)}</div>
```

I wonder why the `escape_javascript` printed as text instead of run as a command? My suspect was because of there is `"` inside the  `$("#schedules").html('#{ escape_javascript render("schedules")}')`, but I have to use the `"`  inside my code.

Thanks!

I am using Rails 4, HAML, Coffeescript and Kaminari.

Below is the code of my controller for delete:

```
schedules_controller.rb

def destroy
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
    @location = Location.find(@schedule.location_id)

    @schedules = Schedule.where(:doctor_id => current_doctor.id, 
      :location_id => params[:location_id] ).order(days_id: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @schedule.destroy
        format.json { head :no_content, status: :ok }
      end
    end
end
```

my main view:

```
index.html.haml

%h2 Your schedules
- @i = 0
.table-responsive
  %table.table.table-striped{:id => "schedules_table"}
    %thead
      %tr
        %th No
        %th Day
        %th Start
        %th End
        %th Away?
        %th Action
    %tbody{:id => "schedules"}
      = render :partial => 'schedules'

    %br/
    %div{:id => "paginator"}
      = paginate @schedules, :remote => true
    %br/
    = link_to 'New Schedule', new_location_schedule_path
    |
    \#{link_to 'Back', doctor_locations_path(current_doctor)}
```

And my partial view:

```
_schedules.html.haml

- @schedules.each_with_index do |schedule, i|
  %tr.numbered_row
    %td.seq=  i + 1
    %td
      = schedule.find_day_name()
    %td= schedule.start_time.strftime("%H:%M")
    %td= schedule.end_time.strftime("%H:%M")
    %td{:id => "#{schedule.id}"}
      %a.status_link.btn.btn-danger.btn-sm{"data-href" => set_schedule_status_path(location_id:     params[:location_id], id: schedule.id), :style => "#{schedule.is_away ? '' : 'display: none'}", :id => "#{schedule.id}"}
        %i.fa.fa-times
        %span Away
      %a.status_link.btn.btn-success.btn-sm{"data-href" => set_schedule_status_path(location_id: params[:location_id] ,id: schedule.id), :style => "#{schedule.is_away ? 'display: none' : '' }", :id => "#{schedule.id}"}
        %i.fa.fa-check-square-o 
        %span Available
    %td
      - concat link_to icon('pencil'), edit_schedule_path(schedule, location_id: params[:location_id])
      - concat " | " 
      - concat link_to icon('remove'), [@location, schedule], method: :delete, remote: :true,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'delete_schedule'
```

Comment: Where's `escape_javascript` defined? If it's a Ruby function then it won't run unless you're processing this as a template. If it's a JS/CS function then it needs to be in double-quotes to be interpolated.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think `escape_javascript` is Ruby function [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html). How can I process that as a template?

Comment: Make it an erb file, but... meh. I thought the whole server-side-generated-javascript template thing kind of died out a few years ago?